# Catch exception for Executor, thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, jvm

For one thread, I catch the `uncaught exception` via below code segments. However, for `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);`, how can I catch uncaught exception?

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread th, Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Uncaught exception: " + ex);
    }
};
```

Comment: Unless your `ExecutorService` has bugs, there will be no uncaught exceptions when submitting `Callables`. For all submitted `Callables` all exceptions are caught and made available through the associated `Future` instance which has been returned by `submit`. You are asking the wrong question…

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overload of the method `newFixedThreadPool`, which accepts a `ThreadFactory`:

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler eh = ...;
ThreadFactory factory = r -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(eh);
    return t;
};
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, factory);
```

Comment: Instead of using runnable, I will use callable then submit task to the executor service. For this case, how can I use factory?

Comment: The code in my answer catches exception caught on the thread-level - not on the task-level. Are you looking for the latter?

Comment: No in the thread level, but with your code how can I submit callable task? I am a bit confused.

Comment: @petaYAN: The threads are always executed with a `Runnable`, never with a `Callable`. When using an `ExecutorService`, the `Runnable` is created internally in the `ExecutorService`, and the `Runnable` can execute several `Callable`s.

Comment: Correct [but pointless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105323/catch-exception-for-executor-thread-pool#comment37264898_24105323)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above answer, you can use Executors defaultThreadFactory and adding your own uncaughtExceptionHandler. It will give better management of threads.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, runnable -> {
        Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(runnable);
        t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((Thread th, Throwable e) -> {e.printStackTrace();});
        return t;
    });
```